# Setting socket based timeout on http request

Tags: node.js, sockets, http, timeout

The code below aborts the request if it takes longer than 10 seconds duration.

Is it possible to set a `socket` based timeout on the request using `http` module?

Also, should I be using a socket and request timeout?

```
var abortRequestError;
var timeout = 10000;
var requestObject = {
  host: 'xx.xx.xx.xx',
  path: '/api',
  port: 10000,
  method: 'GET'
};

var req = http.request(requestObject, function(res) {

  var responseBody = '';
  res.on('data', function(data) {
    responseBody += data;
  });

  res.on('end', function() {
    console.log(abortRequestError);
  });

}).on('error', function(error) {

  error = abortRequestError ? abortRequestError : error;
  console.log(error);

}).setTimeout(timeout, function() {

  abortRequestError = new Error('Request timed out');
  req.abort();
});
```

Comment: Do you mean connection timeout?

Comment: It must only be considered broken if the data flow is interrupted for 10 seconds .. is that connection timeout?

Comment: Your code calls a correct function for what you want to achieve — timeout in socket being idle; perhaps the problem is elsewhere. What are you trying to achieve, what exactly doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **connection timeouts**, Node uses OS defaults. Simplified, these are triggered when you can't reach the server at all within a period of time.

After you established connection, [`request#setTimeout()` function](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback) sets up **idle timeout**, which triggers when there have been no network activity for a period of time. Sounds like this is what you want. (Note that underneath it simply calls [`socket#setTimeout`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback) when socket is created, so there is no need to call both.)

For other kinds of logic, you'll need to set up your own thing with manual usage of [timers](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/docs/api/timers.html). But the code you provided should work just fine for what you need — if, after being connected to, server stops sending data for longer than 10,000 milliseconds, timeout will trigger.